# module not found: io.spray#sbt-revolver;0.7.2 using intellij 14.1.4 with sbt 0.13.5

Tags: scala, sbt, intellij-14

I have tried many things but cant seem to get this to work. 
I have the following in my build.sbt

```
name := "MyTestApp"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

resolvers ++= Seq("spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io",
"Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
"Scalaz Bintray Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
"Plugin Releases" at 
"http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"Io.spray" %% "spray-routing" % "1.3.2",
"io.spray" %% "spray-can" % "1.3.2",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.2.3",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.2.3",
"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.6.4",
"io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.7.2"
)
```

I have also added the following to my plugins.sbt file

```
addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.7.2")
```

I am using scala 2.10 with sbt version 0.13.5
My build log seems to indicate it is trying to resolve at the following location
==== Plugin Releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/io/spray/sbt-revolver/0.7.2/sbt-revolver-0.7.2.pom

Browsing to the following perhaps it would resolve if it was looking in
http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/io.spray/sbt-revolver/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.7.2/

Any ideas as to why io.spray has turned into io/spray in the url

Any help deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Resolver.url("Plugin Releases", url("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

instead of:

```
"Plugin Releases" at "http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"
```

This sets the correct URL pattern for this repository.